# AVAudioPlayer, a lot of sounds

Tags: ios, memory-management, avaudioplayer

In my app I use AVAudioPlayer to play some mp3. My code is:

```
- (void) play{
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                      [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                      [arraysound objectAtIndex:appDelegate.indexSound]];
    NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path isDirectory:NO];
    soundID = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:filePath error:nil];
    soundID.delegate = self;
    [soundID prepareToPlay]; 
    [soundID play];  
}
```

but I have 40 sounds to play; I use everytime soundID to play my sounds

example I have sound1.mp3, sound2.mp3, sound3.mp3......

How can I release my soundId?

When my sound change I call "play" method but this method alloc a new AVAudioPlayer everytime

I Know

```
- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying: (AVAudioPlayer *) player
                    successfully: (BOOL) flag {
```

but I don't understand how to release my sound id inside this delegate method, because if I release inside soundId my app crash
after some minutes that I use my app I have with crash this message "shm_open failed: "Apple Audio Queue"

please help me...thanks

Comment: Are you waiting for each sound to finish where the delegate method is called, or are you manually changing them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to release `soundID` in your delegate method. You want to release `player`. Judging from your code, `soundID` is an ivar. When the delegate gets called, `soundID` may have been set to another value. But the `player` parameter will be the `AVAudioPlayer` that has just finished playing.